# summarize it in 1 line Linq statement?

Tags: c#, linq

I have this code in my C#, how can I summarize it in 1 line Linq statement?

```
        if (UpdatedUser.ModifiedById != 0)
        {
             UpdatedUser = await DbContext.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == UpdatedUser.ModifiedById);
        }
        else
        {
             UpdatedUser = await DbContext.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == UpdatedUser.CreatedById);
        }
```

Comment: You could use an inline ternary branch but it hurts readability. `UpdatedUser = await DbContext.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == UpdatedUser.ModifiedById!=0?UpdatedUser.ModifiedById:UpdatedUser.CreatedById);` I'd suggest something more like: create a temp id var, determine which property from UpdatedUser to use and assign it to the temp id var, use that in the dbcontext call.

Comment: Just because you can (reduce a block of code to one line), doesn't mean you _should_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use a local variable to assign the value to use in the lookup

```
var lookupId = UpdatedUser.ModifiedById != 0
    ? UpdatedUser.ModifiedById
    : UpdatedUser.CreatedById;
UpdatedUser = await DbContext.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == lookupId);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UpdatedUser = await DbContext.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => (UpdatedUser.ModifiedById != 0)?
    (x.Id == UpdatedUser.ModifiedById) :
    (x.Id == UpdatedUser.CreatedById) );
```

I used a ternary operator (`? :`) to figure out if the `ModifiedById` was non-zero, and change the lambda function with that.